# jQuery "Access Is Denied" Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xss, access-denied

I have an `$.ajax()` request that queries currency exchange rate information from another web server, which is the reason (I believe) for which I am getting an "Access Is Denied" error on the `$.ajax()` call.

Is there a way to permit this type of activity?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you could use [JSONP](http://docs.jquery.com/Release:jQuery_1.2/Ajax#Cross-Domain_getJSON_.28using_JSONP.29) if the remote server can support it (works only with GET requests and it works with the [.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) function as well). Another option is to create a bridge server script on the same domain.

Here's [an article](http://remysharp.com/2007/10/08/what-is-jsonp/) that may help you get started.

Here's how it works:

The server must send the data using the following format:

```
callback({name : "Smith", id : 1})
```

where `callback` must be configurable.

So basically jQuery includes a `script` tag inside the DOM:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://distantdomain.com/?jsonp_callback=someRandomName"></script>
```

and the `someRandomName` function will be executed and passed the JSON object.

Comment: Im not so sure I understand how JSONP works in the jQuery ajax method. It speaks of callbacks?

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately the server sends back an xml response, which can't be changed by me, so i'll need to find another way :(

Comment: The callback is an anonymous function that you define and which is called once the response of the server is loaded and this callback is passed the JSON object as argument so that you can manipulate it.

Comment: In case you want a cross browser solution you will need to setup a script on your domain that will delegate the call to the distant server and your AJAX script will query the local server.

Comment: Thanks, nice to have a definitive answer :)

Comment: +1 good advices, i just learned new things, hey JIMBO since it is a definitive answer you are supposed to mark it as an answer (duh)